# How many seconds are there in a day?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

I'm trying to figure out if it's worth using Mutiny costing $6k on a Solar Panel during a `NEWSFLASH: Solar flare!` when it's 12:50 and Power is $180 each but falling.

The basic calculation is (time until night * 180) < 6000? However, the time is not done in hours but in some other time unit which works out as real world seconds.

The solar flare runs out in 88s, giving a potential gross income of $15,840. But there's no indication if night will fall before this.

Comment: I tried searching around but can't remember from my own experience. Nothing concrete comes up so you may be best off doing some self testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info care of some guys on [Discord](https://discord.gg/xpdhTyQ).

**1 second is 10 in-game minutes.** A solar day differs in length depending on planet. On [Mars](https://offworldtradingcompany.gamepedia.com/Mars) the sol is 24:40, on [Ceres](https://offworldtradingcompany.gamepedia.com/Ceres) 9 and on [Io](https://offworldtradingcompany.gamepedia.com/Io) 42:30. This gives the breakdown.

```
Ceres 09:00    54 seconds
Mars  24:40   148 seconds
Io    42:30   255 seconds
```